# Sammy.js : Partial calling/rendering my html twice

Tags: html, knockout.js, sammy.js

I am new to knockout and sammy. I am implementing SPA using Sammy(router) and KnockOut(binding).

I have below code.

```
this.get('#/Page/:operation', function (context) {
            this.partial('templates/Page1.html', { cache: false }).then(function (content) {
                // the first argument to then is the content of the
                // prev operation
                $('#sammyDiv').html(content);
            });
        });
```

When I checked the console it's saying **"You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.(…)"**.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

What's the difference between Partial and Render?

Comment: This looks like trouble. Knockout is not just "binding", it is a system for controlling the entire DOM via a model. If you do DOM manipulation outside the model, you are going to run into problems. I suggest you look at having Sammy route using Knockout components. You don't show here where you call `ko.applyBindings`, but that is what generates the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response and comments. Issue was with Sammy router.

```
this.get('#/Page/:operation', function (context) {
            this.partial('templates/Page1.html', { cache: false }).then(function (content) {
                // the first argument to then is the content of the
                // prev operation
                $('#sammyDiv').html(content);
            });
        });
```

changed to

```
this.get('#/Page/:operation', function (context) {
            this.partial('templates/Page1.html', { cache: false });
        });
```

It worked perfectly fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are injecting new html into the parent which has already been bound. You should either be more specific about which divs you are binding too. I.E on apply bindings to the parent div of the html you injected, or clean and reapply bindings. I use both methods throughout my application.

```
if (isBound("my-div"))
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('my-div'));
ko.applyBindings(myModel, document.getElementById('my-div'));
```

Helper Function:

```
// Checks if Element has Already been Bound (Stops Errors Occuring if already bound as element can't be bound multiple times)
var isBound = function (id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) != null)
        return !!ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(id));
    else
        return false;
};
```

I use this check before all my bindings as a safety net.